# WMS and WFS Connections following upgrade to ArcGIS 10.4?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wms, wfs, arcgis-10.4

We recently upgraded from ArcGIS 10.3 to 10.4.  It turns out 10.4 handles WFS and WMS URLs differently and we now face having to update very many interoperability connections individually, and every historic MXD needs WMS layers replacing.

Any one come across any efficient ways of dealing with this?

We have 10.4 running on a server with WMS and WFS on a separate server - both maintained by outsourced IT.

Comment: In what way does it handle these services differently​?

Comment: WMS connections now split the URL into the generic part and the part that refers to a user - this now goes into 'custom parameters' rather than  being tacked onto the end of the URL.  With regard to WFS it is not currently clear - we have someone trying to work out why all our WFS links are now broken, plus a call in with ESRI, but it is not yet clear.  Repairing the WFS link does not seem to work - we have to add a completely new connection.

Comment: Sorry, an update on WFS.  Links are sporadically working, but we get an 'inconsistent extent' warning when they are loaded.  Zooming to the layer takes us to a scale of 1:1,194,406,118 rather than the (roughly) 1:884,271 it should be.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  At the moment you seem to be talking about two separate issues (one for WMS and the other for WFS), and so (as per the [Tour]) I think you need to split it into two separate questions.  For each I think we need more precise details like those you have in your comment.